# Subset notation in Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation

I have been reading through the Han Lin book on elliptic PDEs and am confused with some of the notation they are using.

For one, they use $A\Subset B$ to mean $\overline{A}$ is a compact subset of B.

In the third chapter (pg 53), they use $\subset_+$ to denote what seems to be a proper subset.

Am I right on this?

Also, are there any resources that explain common notation in analysis? They don't explain any of the notation in the book, and since I don't have that much experience in this subject I am often left confused by what they mean.

Comment: I have never ever saw such notations. Maybe look into the book if they define "proper subset" somewhere (what about ctrl+f?).

Comment: Just had a look. They only mention proper subsets once in the book and there is no associated symbol.

Comment: I have seen $A\Subset B$ used in the way suggested.

Comment: Does this notation appear anywhere else in the book? Could it be a typo? I also never saw it and tried to look at google, but I had no lucky.

Comment: @YgorArthur Just had a quick control f and didn't see anywhere else in the book. Could well be a typo, I've noticed a few others earlier in the book.